# Install anaconda on ARM Cortex-A9 platform

Tags: python, gcc, android-ndk, arm, anaconda

**Base situation:**

1. Platform: ARM Cortex-A9 (32-bit processor)
2. OS: Ubuntu Mate 16.04.4
3. gcc version: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1-16.04.4) 5.4.0 201606609
4. python version: 2.7.12

**Question:**

I want to install anaconda on ARM Cortex-A9 platform. However, when I execute:

```
 $./Anaconda2-5.0.1-Linux-x86.sh
```

It return an error:

```
/root/anaconda2/pkgs/python-2.7.14-h41cc02d_21/bin/python:1: /root/anaconda2/pkgs/python-2.7.14-h41cc02d_21/bin/python:Syntax error:word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

How I can fit this problem? How I can install anaconda on ARM platform?

Tks.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to run the command like this:

```
$ bash Anaconda2-5.0.1-Linux-x86.sh
```

because it's actually a bash script :)